# CMake 3 Link Libraries Using Relative Paths

Tags: makefile, build, cmake

I've got a shared library source directory that needs to be formatted in a particular way, and I've been unsuccessful in getting CMake to allow building of individual libraries.

Here's a basic example of the directories

```
libraries/
    CMakeLists.txt
    a/
        CMakeLists.txt    
        a.h
        src/a.cpp
        test/
            CMakeLists.txt
            exe_test.cpp
    b/
        CMakeLists.txt    
        b.h
        src/b.cpp
```

Library `a` depends on `b`. If I `add_subdirectory()` for both of them in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, I can build the whole libraries folder using cmake. However, I don't want to do this. I'd like to be able to build *just* `b`, and if I choose to build `a`, it automatically links to `b` using relative paths. For this example it may seem trivial, but imagine roughly two dozen libraries in this kind of format, and we'd like to avoid nesting.

`target_link_libraries(a PUBLIC ../b)` does not work. Neither does `add_subdirectory(..)`.

Comment: "links to b using relative paths." - You build the library `b` in the same project, so you may specify just `b` for `target_link_libraries`, and CMake automatically finds this target and performs appropriate linking. No needs to use path to the library in that case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The problem with that is that CMake doesn't know where to find it. The only way it seems to is if I always build from the top libraries level. `add_subdirectories()` seems to force it to generate builds for the specified directory.

Comment: My desired behavior is being able to run `cmake path/to/b` and it doesn't build `a`, and run `cmake path/to/a` and it builds `b` and then `a`

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem... You write `However, I don't want to do this.`, but what **exactly** do you want to avoid? You just don't want to have all libraries in the single project? Or it is acceptable for you, and you just don't want to build all libraries by **default**? In the latter case, just add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to the `add_library` call. That way the library will be built only when explicitely requested, or it is needed for build another library.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to run `cmake rel/path/to/libraries/` and having the entire project built. There are 4 teams of about 4 devs each who aren't all going to need every library built for their microservice to be testable. This isn't a problem when the directory structure is based on dependencies (`libraries/a/b`) but my boss wants a flat libs folder, not nested.

Comment: Building one library (by its relative path, or just by its name) doesn't enforce other libraries to be built until they are used by the requested one.